# Android : Get network operator name in dual SIM phone while reading SMS programmatically

Tags: android

I am trying to read all the inbox sms using `Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");`. 
I am able to read all the messages successfully and getting all columns value using `Cursor`. My Device is dual SIM device. Here is my question :
`How can I know that given sms is belongs to which network operator? I want network operator name.`

Observation : 
There is a column name `sub_id` whose value is integer number. For all messages I am getting only two different values(In my case, I am getting either `5` or `4`) of `sub_id`. Messages whose `sub_id` value is `5` belongs to one network operator and messages whose `sub_id` values is `4` belongs to another network operator.

Additional question : What does `sub_id` represent? How can I get network operators name using `sub_id`?

My App's minimum SDK level is API 19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Private API in Android for that :
telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName(int subId)

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.java#1476

It's the same as the public API telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName, but with a SubID.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperatorName()

But, it's a private API, so you need to ask this request with Java Reflection